# logistic transform and untransform interpretation

Tags: regression, logistic, logit

I was looking at this link:

I have a dataset that has a proportion outcome (0,1). I wanted to do a beta regression using betareg BUT I also want to do a mixed model and currently I don't think there is a package for that so.  Below is a toy dataset. I was going to use the logit transform (see here http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/logit-transformation/) on the proportion  like this with lme4:

```
library(betareg)
d= data.frame(
  DAY = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
  Proportion = c(.4,.1,.25, .25, .5,.3,.1,.1),
  MACHINE=c("A","B","C","D","H","G","K","L"),
  TEMPERATURE = c(rnorm(8)*100)
)
d$LOGIT = log(d$Proportion/(1-d$Proportion))
d

library(nlme)
lm = lme(fixed= LOGIT ~ TEMPERATURE ,
         random = ~1|MACHINE, data =d )
summary(lm)
```

The results are below and my question is on the interpretation of the TEMPERATURE coefficient .0033. That is saying  a one unit increase in TEMPERATURE will increase the logit of the proportion .0033- correct?  That is difficult to interpret so can you convert the coefficient in that same manner that you exponentiate the coefficients of a logistic regression? ....OR how do you explain this .0033 coefficient to  lay person who has no idea what increasing the logit means?

Thank you.

```
Linear mixed-effects model fit by REML
 Data: d 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  36.39584 35.56288 -14.19792

Random effects:
 Formula: ~1 | MACHINE
        (Intercept)  Residual
StdDev:   0.8127609 0.3047853

Fixed effects: LOGIT ~ TEMPERATURE 
                 Value Std.Error DF   t-value p-value
(Intercept) -1.4962022 0.4013192  6 -3.728210  0.0098
TEMPERATURE  0.0033267 0.0035697  6  0.931928  0.3873
 Correlation: 
            (Intr)
TEMPERATURE -0.644

Standardized Within-Group Residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-0.4763054 -0.2610879  0.0737390  0.2395532  0.3788591
```

Comment: Are these proportions count proportions (a count divided by a total count)?

Comment: yes the proportions are divided by a total count

Comment: Then why not binomial GLM rather than beta regression?

Comment: Typically when proportions (0,1) are the dependent variable beta regression is used

Comment: For *continuous* proportions, sure. But these are count proportions -- the counts in the numerator are simply aggregated 0/1 data (i.e. a sum) across each of the subjects in the denominator of the proportion. Which is to say, with count proportions you have exactly the situation people would apply  logistic regression to